# Compare two arrays using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

In PHP I am going to edit some entity let say a **project named: ABC** this projects belongs to many **countries** while adding this project I used `<select multiple="multiple">` and store all selected countries in a **projectCountries** table. Now when I start editing this project so I use same logic with a little change:

1. populate all countries from countries table
2. fetch all countries from projectCountries table which are associate with projectId

and I got two arrays:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [countryId] => 1 [countryName] => Pakistan ) 
    [1] => Array ( [countryId] => 2 [countryName] => China ) 
)
```

output from step-1

and

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [pcId] => 1 [countryId] => 1 [projectId] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [pcId] => 2 [countryId] => 2 [projectId] => 1 ) 
)
```

output from step-2

but I am confused how to show that country named China was already associated with the project (already selected in `<select multiple="multiple">`)

because to create `<select multiple="multiple">` I used **foreach** loop. Now I could not guess how to compare two arrays in **foreach** loop so that I set `selected="selected"` in `<option>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over all countries and check if that country exists on the `projectCountries` output array.

Something like this:

```
$pc_list = array();
foreach($project_countries as $pc) {
    $pc_list[] = $pc['countryId'];  
}

foreach($countries as &$country) {
    if(in_array($country['countryId'], $pc_list)) {
        $country['selected'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
Run the foreach loop for step1. In every iteration you could iterate through the second array and check if there is a country with the current id (from the first loop).

**Option 2:**
Change your SQL-Query to something like that (with a join for example):

CountryId CountryName ProjectId
1         Pakistan    1
2         China       1
3         Germany     null